# Generating all Possible Combinations of a Sentence with Variables

Tags: string, algorithm

Say I have a sentence with *multiple variables* as follows:

```
"lorem ipsum {a, b} dolor {c, d, e} sit amet"
```

Assuming the letters in the braces are *variables*, how would one go about generating a group of sentences out of *all possible combinations* of the variables?

**Note:**
The *number of variable groups* or variable *count within each group* of variables is *unknown*.

---

The expected output for this particular example would be:

```
"lorem ipsum {a} dolor {c} sit amet"
"lorem ipsum {b} dolor {c} sit amet"
"lorem ipsum {a} dolor {d} sit amet"
"lorem ipsum {b} dolor {d} sit amet"
"lorem ipsum {a} dolor {e} sit amet"
"lorem ipsum {b} dolor {e} sit amet"
```

Comment: Could, please, you provide the desired output for the example in the question?

Comment: Any specific language you are working with?

Comment: any language or pseudocode is fine

Comment: Is the number of variables known? As in the number of brackets in the sentence?
Anyhow i suppose this could be done with an approach of binary counting of tuples.

Comment: You could, for example, write this as a recursive function -- iterating over each variable array until none are left.

Comment: All you need is just 2 for loops(nested)! You could have tried.

Comment: @vivek_23: in general case - "The number of variable groups or variable count within each group of variables is unknown" - we don't know number of loops; the solution is not that easy.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ok, the note wasn't pretty clear before. But still 3(sorry not 2) loops should be enough where you store temp elements and iterate next set of elements over this temp result and create new temp result. 3 loop nested should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *general case* ("number of variable groups... count within each group ... is *unknown*") we should *parse* the initial string (let's do it with a help of *regular expressions*) and then *enumerate* all the combinations.

**C# Code:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

private static IEnumerable<string> Generator(string source) {
  // parsing: variables extracted: array of variables and their possible values
  string[][] variables = Regex
    .Matches(source, @"\{.*?\}")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match
       .Value
       .Trim('{', '}')
       .Split(',')
       .Select(item => "{" + item.Trim() + "}")
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();

  // now we should enumerate all possible variables' values
  int[] indexes = new int[variables.Length];

  do {
    // code golf : ugly side effects but short code
    int at = 0;

    yield return Regex.Replace(source, @"\{.*?\}", match => variables[at][indexes[at++]]);

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; ++i)
      if (indexes[i] < variables[i].Length - 1) {
        indexes[i] = indexes[i] + 1;

        break;
      }
      else
        indexes[i] = 0;
  }
  while (!indexes.All(index => index == 0));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string source = @"lorem ipsum {a, b} dolor {c, d, e} sit amet";

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Generator(source));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
lorem ipsum {a} dolor {c} sit amet
lorem ipsum {b} dolor {c} sit amet
lorem ipsum {a} dolor {d} sit amet
lorem ipsum {b} dolor {d} sit amet
lorem ipsum {a} dolor {e} sit amet
lorem ipsum {b} dolor {e} sit amet
```

**Another example:**

```
// 3 groups of variables with strange names
string source = @"lorem ipsum {A + 2, B, C?} dolor {XY, PQR} sit {eh?, bla-bla-bla} amet";

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Generator(source)));
```

**Outcome:**

```
lorem ipsum {A + 2} dolor {XY} sit {eh?} amet
lorem ipsum {B} dolor {XY} sit {eh?} amet
lorem ipsum {C?} dolor {XY} sit {eh?} amet
lorem ipsum {A + 2} dolor {PQR} sit {eh?} amet
lorem ipsum {B} dolor {PQR} sit {eh?} amet
lorem ipsum {C?} dolor {PQR} sit {eh?} amet
lorem ipsum {A + 2} dolor {XY} sit {bla-bla-bla} amet
lorem ipsum {B} dolor {XY} sit {bla-bla-bla} amet
lorem ipsum {C?} dolor {XY} sit {bla-bla-bla} amet
lorem ipsum {A + 2} dolor {PQR} sit {bla-bla-bla} amet
lorem ipsum {B} dolor {PQR} sit {bla-bla-bla} amet
lorem ipsum {C?} dolor {PQR} sit {bla-bla-bla} amet
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to iterate two different arrays for all possible combinations of a single value from each array - Nested loops is probably the best option.

Here's a c# code to do that, with comments on each line for easy translation to other languages:

```
var values0 = new string[] {"a", "b"}; // All possible values for first slot
var values1 = new string[] {"c", "d", "e"}; // All possible values for second slot

foreach(var val0 in values0) // Iterate first array
{
    foreach(var val1 in values1) // Iterate second array
    {
        var result = $"Lorem ipsum {val0} dolor {val1} sit amet"; // Insert values to slots
        Console.WriteLine(str); // output
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Lorem ipsum a dolor c sit amet
Lorem ipsum a dolor d sit amet
Lorem ipsum a dolor e sit amet
Lorem ipsum b dolor c sit amet
Lorem ipsum b dolor d sit amet
Lorem ipsum b dolor e sit amet
```